# The collection of the uions of null sets and the sets in an $\sigma$-algebra form a complete space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space, $\Omega$ is non-empty.

Let $\tilde{\Sigma}=\{E\cup Z, \, Z \text{ is a null set}\}$,
$\tilde{\mu}(E\cup Z) = \mu(E)$, if $E\in \Sigma$, $Z$ is null.

Prove $(\Omega, \tilde{\Sigma}, \tilde{\mu})$ is a complete measure space.
($Z$ is a null set, if there exists a set $F\in \Sigma$, $Z\subset F$ and $\mu(F)=0$.)

I have done the part of "$(\Omega, \tilde{\Sigma}, \tilde{\mu})$ is a measure space". But I am not sure how to show it is complete.

My process: Let $A\in\tilde{\Sigma}$ with $\tilde{\mu}(A)=0$. There exists $E_1\in\Sigma$ and $Z_1$ a null set s.t. $A=E_1\cup Z_1$ and $0=\tilde{\mu}(A)=\mu(E_1)$. Let $B$ be a subset of $A$, then we have the following cases

1. $B \subset E_1$, then $B \cap Z_1= \emptyset $. By the definition of null sets, $B \cap Z_1$ is a null set.
2. $B \subset Z_1$, then $B \cap E_1= \emptyset $. By the definition, $B$ is a null set and $\emptyset\in \Sigma$. Hence, $B\in\tilde{\Sigma}$.
3. Otherwise, let $E_2=B\cap E_1$ and $Z_2=B\cap Z_1$. Z_2 is again a null set.

What can I do from 1. and 3.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $B\subseteq A\in\tilde{\Sigma}$ and $\tilde{\mu}A=0$.

Then for showing the completeness of $\tilde{\mu}$ it is enough to prove
that $B\in\tilde{\Sigma}$.

$\tilde{\Sigma}$ contains every set that is a null-set wrt $\mu$ so it is enough to prove that $B$ is indeed a null-set wrt $\mu$.

Sets $E$, $F$ and $Z\subseteq F$ exist with $E,F\in\Sigma$ and
$\mu F=0$ and $A=E\cup Z$.

Then $B\subseteq A\subseteq E\cup F\in\Sigma$ and $\mu\left(E\cup F\right)\leq\mu E+\mu F=0$.

Proved is now that $B$ is a null-set wrt $\mu$ so we are ready.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that "every null set contained in $\tilde{\Sigma}$". Thank you!